# Get generated API key from AWS AppSync API created with CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-appsync

I'm trying to access data from my stack where I'm creating an AppSync API. I want to be able to use the generated Stacks' `url` and `apiKey` but I'm running into issues with them being encoded/tokenized.

In my stack I'm setting some fields to the outputs of the deployed stack:

```
this.ApiEndpoint = graphAPI.url;
this.Authorization = graphAPI.graphqlApi.apiKey;
```

When trying to access these properties I get something like `${Token[TOKEN.209]}` and not the values.

If I'm trying to resolve the token like so: `this.resolve(graphAPI.graphqlApi.apiKey)` I instead get `{ 'Fn::GetAtt': [ 'AppSyncAPIApiDefaultApiKey537321373E', 'ApiKey' ] }`.

But I would like to retrieve the key itself as a string, like `da2-10lksdkxn4slcrahnf4ka5zpeemq5i`.

How would I go about actually extracting the string values for these properties?

Answer (score 1):

The actual values of such [Tokens](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/tokens.html) are available only at deploy-time.  Before then you can safely pass these token properties between constructs in your CDK code, but they are opaque placeholders until deployed.  Depending on your use case, one of these options can help retrieve the deploy-time values:

If you define CloudFormation Outputs for a variable, CDK will (apart from creating it in CloudFormation), will, after `cdk deploy`, print its value to the console and optionally write it to a `json` file you pass with the `--outputs-file` flag.

```js
// AppsyncStack.ts
new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'ApiKey', {
  value: this.api.apiKey ?? 'UNDEFINED',
  exportName: 'api-key',
});
```

```json
// at deploy-time, if you use a flag: --outputs-file cdk.outputs.json
{
  "AppsyncStack": {
    "ApiKey": "da2-ou5z5di6kjcophixxxxxxxxxx",
    "GraphQlUrl": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql"
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can write a script to fetch the data post-deploy using the [listGraphqlApis](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-appsync/classes/appsync.html#listgraphqlapis) and [listApiKeys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-appsync/classes/appsync.html#listapikeys) commands from the [appsync JS SDK client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-appsync/index.html).  You can run the script locally or, for advanced use cases, wrap the script in a [CDK Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib-readme.html#custom-resources) construct for deploy-time integration.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @fedonev I was able to extract the API key and url like so:

```js
const client = new AppSyncClient({ region: "eu-north-1" });
  const command = new ListGraphqlApisCommand({ maxResults: 1 });
  const res = await client.send(command);
  if (res.graphqlApis) {
    const apiKeysCommand = new ListApiKeysCommand({
      apiId: res.graphqlApis[0].apiId,
    });
    const apiKeyResponse = await client.send(apiKeysCommand);
    const urls = flatMap(res.graphqlApis[0].uris);
    if (apiKeyResponse.apiKeys && res.graphqlApis[0].uris) {
      sendSlackMessage(urls[1], apiKeyResponse.apiKeys[0].id || "");
    }
  }
```